# Avoid Alphabetical order on python finance download

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am downloading data from yahoo finance, and it is being downloaded order alphabetically. Not like I send the list. How can avoid this?

```
STOCKS= ['^TNX', '^VIX', 'SPY', 'QQQ', 'DIA', '^FTSE', '^GDAXI', '^HSI', '^N225',
    'XLC', 'XLY', 'XLP', 'XLE', 'XLF', 'XLV', 'XLI', 'XLB', 'XLRE', 'XLK', 'XLU',
     'USO', 'GLD', 'SIL', 'CPER', 'PALL', 'LIT', 'URA', 'REMX', 'OYB', 'CORN', 'CANE', 'TAGS', 'WEAT']



start_date = '2016-06-01'
end_date = '2018-06-01'

extras_data = fyf.download(STOCKS, start_date, end_date)['Close']
print(extras_data)
```

what came back:

```
     CANE       CORN    ...       ^TNX       ^VIX
```

Date                            ...
2016-05-31  11.50  22.139999    ...      1.834  14.190000
2016-06-01  11.56  22.610001    ...      1.846  14.200000
2016-06-02  11.85  22.549999    ...      1.811  13.630000
2016-06-03  12.13  22.760000    ...      1.704  13.470000

The columns are order alphabetically, I want to respect the list order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
"your code here"

#after pulling the data from fyf. This will check what
#actual stocks were pulled and put it in a list

sorted_columns = [STOCK for STOCK in STOCKS if STOCK in extras_data.columns]

#then I use those columns to re-sort the dataframe from fyf
print(extras_data.loc[:,sorted_columns])

#or you can store it back to itself
extras_data = extras_data.loc[:,sorted_columns]
```